# I have 9 radio groups and and each radio group have 4 possible answers i want to to take the result according to the according to code...it crashes

Tags: android, android-studio, radio-button, radio-group

This is java code....Kindley make this code running for me plz i Want to show the result in val variable.I have 9 radio groups and and each radio group have 4 possible answers i want to to take the result according to the according to code...it crashes ........................................................................................................................................

```
 package com.bj.smartpsychologist;
    import androidx.annotation.IdRes;
    import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.Gravity;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.RadioButton;
    import android.widget.RadioGroup;
    import android.widget.Toast;
    
    public class Activity_Survey_Phq extends AppCompatActivity {
    
        private RadioGroup r_g_1,r_g_2,r_g_3,r_g_4,r_g_5,r_g_6,r_g_7,r_g_8,r_g_9;
    
        private Button result;
        private int val=0;
    
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_survey_phq);
    
            //radio groups
            r_g_1=findViewById(R.id.q_1_radioGroup);
            r_g_2=findViewById(R.id.q_2_radioGroup);
            r_g_3=findViewById(R.id.q_3_radioGroup);
            r_g_4=findViewById(R.id.q_4_radioGroup);
            r_g_5=findViewById(R.id.q_5_radioGroup);
            r_g_6=findViewById(R.id.q_6_radioGroup);
            r_g_7=findViewById(R.id.q_7_radioGroup);
            r_g_8=findViewById(R.id.q_8_radioGroup);
            r_g_9=findViewById(R.id.q_9_radioGroup);
    
            result=findViewById(R.id.btn_check_result);
    
            addListenerOnButton();
    
        }
    
        private void addListenerOnButton() {
    
            result.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
    
                    r_g_1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
                            RadioButton radioButton = (RadioButton) group.findViewById(checkedId);
    
                            if(radioButton.getText().toString().trim().equals("Not at all"))
                                val=val+0;
    
                            else if(radioButton.getText().toString().trim().equals("Several days"))
                                val=val+1;
    
    
                            else if(radioButton.getText().toString().trim().equals("More than half the days"))
                                val=val+2;
    
                            else if(radioButton.getText().toString().trim().equals("Nearly every day"))
                                val=val+3;
                        }
                    });
    
                    r_g_2.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
                            RadioButton radioButton = (RadioButton) group.findViewById(checkedId);
    
                            if(radioButton.getText().toString().trim().equals("Not at all"))
                                val=val+0;
    
                            else if(radioButton.getText().toString().trim().equals("Several days"))
                                val=val+1;
    
    
                            else if(radioButton.getText().toString().trim().equals("More than half the days"))
                                val=val+2;
    
                            else if(radioButton.getText().toString().trim().equals("Nearly every day"))
                                val=val+3;
                        }
                    });
    
    
    
    
                    r_g_3.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
                            RadioButton radioButton = (RadioButton) group.findViewById(checkedId);
    
    
                            if(radioButton.getText().toString().trim().equals("Not at all"))
                                val=val+0;
    
                            else if(radioButton.getText().toString().trim().equals("Several days"))
                                val=val+1;
    
    
                            else if(radioButton.getText().toString().trim().equals("More than half the days"))
                                val=val+2;
    
                            else if(radioButton.getText().toString().trim().equals("Nearly every day"))
                                val=val+3;
                        }
                    });
    
    
    
    
                    r_g_4.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
                            RadioButton radioButton = (RadioButton) group.findViewById(checkedId);
    
    
                            if(radioButton.getText().toString().trim().equals("Not at all"))
                                val=val+0;
    
                            else if(radioButton.getText().toString().trim().equals("Several days"))
                                val=val+1;
    
    
                            else if(radioButton.getText().toString().trim().equals("More than half the days"))
                                val=val+2;
    
                            else if(radioButton.getText().toString().trim().equals("Nearly every day"))
                                val=val+3;
                        }
                    });
    
    
    
    
                    r_g_5.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
                            RadioButton radioButton = (RadioButton) group.findViewById(checkedId);
    
    
                            if(radioButton.getText().toString().trim().equals("Not at all"))
                                val=val+0;
    
                            else if(radioButton.getText().toString().trim().equals("Several days"))
                                val=val+1;
    
    
                            else if(radioButton.getText().toString().trim().equals("More than half the days"))
                                val=val+2;
    
                            else if(radioButton.getText().toString().trim().equals("Nearly every day"))
                                val=val+3;
                        }
                    });
    
    
    
    
                    r_g_6.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
                            RadioButton radioButton = (RadioButton) group.findViewById(checkedId);
    
    
                            if(radioButton.getText().toString().trim().equals("Not at all"))
                                val=val+0;
    
                            else if(radioButton.getText().toString().trim().equals("Several days"))
                                val=val+1;
    
    
                            else if(radioButton.getText().toString().trim().equals("More than half the days"))
                                val=val+2;
    
                            else if(radioButton.getText().toString().trim().equals("Nearly every day"))
                                val=val+3;
                        }
                    });
    
    
    
    
    
                    r_g_7.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
                            RadioButton radioButton = (RadioButton) group.findViewById(checkedId);
    
    
                            if(radioButton.getText().toString().trim().equals("Not at all"))
                                val=val+0;
    
                            else if(radioButton.getText().toString().trim().equals("Several days"))
                                val=val+1;
    
    
                            else if(radioButton.getText().toString().trim().equals("More than half the days"))
                                val=val+2;
    
                            else if(radioButton.getText().toString().trim().equals("Nearly every day"))
                                val=val+3;
                        }
                    });
    
    
    
    
    
                    r_g_8.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
                            RadioButton radioButton = (RadioButton) group.findViewById(checkedId);
    
    
                            if(radioButton.getText().toString().trim().equals("Not at all"))
                                val=val+0;
    
                            else if(radioButton.getText().toString().trim().equals("Several days"))
                                val=val+1;
    
    
                            else if(radioButton.getText().toString().trim().equals("More than half the days"))
                                val=val+2;
    
                            else if(radioButton.getText().toString().trim().equals("Nearly every day"))
                                val=val+3;
                        }
                    });
    
    
    
    
                    r_g_9.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
                            RadioButton radioButton = (RadioButton) group.findViewById(checkedId);
    
                            if(radioButton.getText().toString().trim().equals("Not at all"))
                                val=val+0;
    
                            else if(radioButton.getText().toString().trim().equals("Several days"))
                                val=val+1;
    
    
                            else if(radioButton.getText().toString().trim().equals("More than half the days"))
                                val=val+2;
    
                            else if(radioButton.getText().toString().trim().equals("Nearly every day"))
                                val=val+3;
    
    
                        }
                    });
    
    
                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(Activity_Survey_Phq.this, val, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                    toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
                    toast.show();
    
    
                }});}
    
    
    
        }
```

Comment: You said "_it crashes_" , please add the crash log

Comment: it crashes when i uses the toast ...

Comment: when i remove the toast it work properly i use intent inside click listner it works but toast crashes

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a minimal reproducible example. 
Furthermore, as Mouaad said, please not only say when the app crashes, but add the "Crash Log" (what is printed in the console when the program crashes).